# Shuffle element such that, no element should come at its original index

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, permutation, shuffle

I have a list of Object elements

```
SourceList    ResultList (Expected)

Obj_A                 Obj_F

Obj_B                 Obj_C

Obj_C                 Obj_G

Obj_D                 Obj_B

Obj_E                 Obj_A

Obj_F                 Obj_B

Obj_G                 Obj_E
```

Shuffle elements in ***SourceList*** such that, no element should come at its original index(in ***SourceList***) in ***ResultList***.

For Example, in ***SourceList*** C is at index 2, so it must not come at index 2 in ***ResultList***

So far, i have looked into [Dearrangement Wiki](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations/Derangements#Java) , but algo gives me possible arrangements and i need just one.

Comment: I assume that you're ruling out having to operate on lists of exactly one element.

Comment: You can achieve this if you simply rotate the array (shift each element's index by 1 and have the last element come to the front). How "shuffled" do you need the resulting array?

Comment: Also note, by a uniform random shuffle (like fisher yates), you have probability of `1/e` to get a dearrangement. This means you can repeat the process until you get one, and it will cost expected number of e~= 2.7 permutations, so it will take `O(n)` average case to get a dearrangement, and it is guaranteed to be unbiased and all dearrangements are attainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var SourceList = new List<string>()
{
    "Obj_A", "Obj_B", "Obj_C", "Obj_D", "Obj_E", "Obj_F", "Obj_G",
}; 

var rnd = new Random();

var ResultList =
    Enumerable
        // create an exceedingly long sequence for retries
        .Repeat(0, int.MaxValue)
        // select and randomly order all of the indices of `SourceList`
        .Select(_ => Enumerable.Range(0, SourceList.Count)
            .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
            .ToArray())
        // Discard the indices if they have any matching positions
        .Where(x => !x.Where((y, i) => y == i).Any())
        // only take one successful set of indices
        .Take(1)
        // flatten the list of lists to a list
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        // select the elements from `SourceList` from their index positions
        .Select(x => SourceList[x])
        // convert to list
        .ToList();
```

The use of `.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())` produces a uniform ordering (no bias) - I have confirmed this in the past.

Comment: In an algorithm tag question (and actually, in any question, but expecially  algorithm) "This works for me"+ Code is a poor answer. Please describe the logic. The community expect much better quality answers from high rep users.

Comment: Please elaborate in the explanation: (1) Explanation (2) Why it works (3) Why is it unbiased (4) Why every dearrangement is attainable.

Comment: @amit - explanation added.

Comment: The explanation is unsatisfactory. It explains why you get a random permutation, not a random dearrangement (do you get one?). Also, "I have confirmed this in the past" is hardly an explanation. In addition, it is inefficient in terms of time complexity. (finding a permutation cab be done in a single pass, no need to sort).

Comment: @amit - Please re-read "// Discard the indices if they have any matching positions". Also this is hardly going to have a terrible amount of time complexity. In my tests I got a maximum of 12 retries with 1 retry being the median.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't see the comments, only the `.OrderBy(..)` explanation. The time complexity is due to the sort, which is `O(nlogn)`, where there is an `O(n)` solution.

Comment: @amit - I agree with the complexity, but I did run a test with 70,000,000 elements in the source list and it ran quite quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fisher-yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) as a black box, and repeatidly shuffle your array until your result is a dearrangement.

Pseudo code:

```
while true:
     arr = [1,2,...,n]
     shuffle(arr)
     flag = true
     for i from 0 to n:
        if arr[i] == i: //not a dearrangement
           flag = false 
     if flag == true: //it's a dearrangement
        break

shuffle(arr): //fisher yates
    for i from 0 to n:
       j = rand(i,n)
       swap(arr,i,j)
```

**Properties of this approach:**

- This is guaranteed to be **uniform and ubiased**, because every valid rearrangement
  gets exactly the same odds to be picked in each iteration.
- Since Fisher-Yates generates all permutations, and we invalidate only dearrangement - **every dearrangement is attainable**.
- The probability to get a dearrangement is 1/e<sup>1</sup>, this means you are going to need (1-1/e)^-1 ~=1.56 shuffles on the average case, which means this algorithm runs in **`O(n)` expected time complexity**.

---

(1) [The number of dearrangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) is `int(n!/e + 1/2)`, this means the probability for an array to be a dearrangement is `(n!/e + 1/2)/n! ~= 1/e`, for large values of `n`.

Comment: Be aware that an array with only 1 element will lead to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Do the shuffle, and get all the elements having index un-changed, then rotate  positions for all these faulty ones.

Comment: This solution seems biased to me.

Comment: this will the simple to do. and i guess rotation of every element (which has same index after shuffle) couldnt be a issue. right

Comment: It could, because I suspect you have higher probability to get some permutations than others.

Comment: For example, you have two (at least) possibilities to make `[2,3,4,5,6,1]`, this and there are other permutations where you have only one possibility to get (I assume [3,2,4,5,6,1] is one of them, though not sure)