# How to randomize an array such that no element is in its original position

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm supposed to take an array of integers that starts from 0 and goes up to the length-1 of some other int array called cards (that has a user-inputted length) and completely randomize it such that no number is in its original position.
I figured out how to generate the first array, but I have absolutely no idea how to completely randomize an array, can anyone help?
So far I have:

```java
int size = cards.length;
int[] numberList = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    numberList[i] = i;
}
```

Update:

```java
private int[] shuffleIndex() {
    int size = cards.length;
    int[] numberList = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        numberList[i] = i;
    }
    randomizer(numberList);
    return numberList;
}
    
private int[] randomizer(int[] input) {
    
    int size = input.length;
    
    Random random = new Random();
    
    for (int i = size -1; i > 0; i--) {
        int j = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        int temp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[j];
        input[j] = temp;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    
        if(input[i] == i) {
            randomizer(input);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: How do you prevent your randomization from getting the same element though? That's what I initially tried but it wasn't working.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming in-place shuffling.

Comment: @GS1221 - I suggest you add an explanation, why [`shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List,%20java.util.Random)) from `Collections` would not suffice, to your question.

Comment: This answer is for C#, but you should be able to convert it to Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28740197/6395627. It essentially just repeats the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm until the "no element at original position" condition is met.

Comment: I was told not to use ArrayLists on this assignment and from what I can tell, it looks like shuffle from Collections uses ArrayLists. I might have found a solution using the Fisher-Yates shuffle that some people were mentioning, do you mind checking it? I'll add it to the "So far I have" section in the original question

Comment: The algorithm in your update is a very effective one: for each entry linearly, swap it with a random other.  That's the algorithm used by std::shuffle in most C++ standard library implementations.

Comment: I understand the assignment says what it says, but I have to mention, the constraint "such that no number is in its original position" means that the result is not truly random. True randomness could, as unlikely as it is, result in an array that is exactly the same as the original array. This comment is, however, inconsequential to a solution.

Comment: I completely agree, I'm not quite sure what I was thinking when I wrote it. Maybe something like "Each element would get moved to a separate place so it is completely different therefore completely random." Really bad logic on my part.

Comment: What do you do when the input is `[0]`?  Your code throws `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shuffle an array of strings so that the sting must be completely shuffled and not in its original index in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146340/shuffle-an-array-of-strings-so-that-the-sting-must-be-completely-shuffled-and-no)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
int size = cards.length;
int[] numberList = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    numberList[i] = i;
}
shuffle(numberList);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numberList));
```

If the array contained ints 1-12, this is an example of the output.

```
[7, 12, 1, 2, 8, 9, 6, 4, 11, 5, 10, 3]
```

Here is how it works.

- start out with `size` set to array size
- Iterate until size == 1
- grab the last element in the array
- generate a random position `exclusive of the value of size` to move it to
- swap that element with the one in the last position.
- decrement the size to preserve the new last element.  The next call to `nextInt()` will not touch it since it was decremented.
- since the random number generated is exclusive of the position to be swapped no element will ever occupy its original position.

```
public static void shuffle(int[] arr) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int size = arr.length;
    while (size-- > 1) {
        int item = r.nextInt(size);
        int t = arr[size];
        arr[size] = arr[item];
        arr[item] = t;
    }
}
```